# Angle between vectors returning a Nan

Tags: java, arrays, math, vector, angle

I've been trying to return the angle between vectors, and after several attempts, all that's been printing is "NaN".

```
public static void displayVector(double v) {
        System.out.print(v);    
}
// magnitude
public static double magnitude(int[] v) {
    double mag = 0;
    for (int i:v) {
        mag += Math.pow(i, 2);
    }
    mag = Math.sqrt(mag);
    return mag;
}
// angle between vectors
public static double angle(int[] v1, int[] v2) {
    double loopSum = 0;
    double magSum = magnitude(v1) + magnitude(v2);
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.length; i++) {
        loopSum += (v1[i]*v2[i]);
    }
    double angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(loopSum / magSum));
    return angle;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] A = {2, 5, 7};
    int[] B = {6, 3, 1};
    Helper.displayVector(Helper.angle(A, B));       
}
```

Comment: A.B = |A| * |B| * cos(theta) - you should be multiplying the two magnitudes, not adding them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is wrong.

The angle is the dot product divided by the product of magnitudes
Your code calculates the sum of magnitudes making it smaller than the dot product (loopSum) and therefore calculating acos of a value greater than 1

Change it to

```
double magProd = magnitude(v1) * magnitude(v2);
```

Then

```
double angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(loopSum / magProd));
```

And it should work like a charm